# Django datatable and enum

Tags: python, django, enums

I have a campaign model as follows:

```
id campaign    objective             platform
1  Hello Word  MOBILE_APP_ENGAGEMENT Facebook
2  Hi There    VIDEO_VIEWS_PREROLL   Twitter
```

Model:

```
class Campaign(Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(default="")
    objective = models.TextField(null=True)
    platform = enumfields.EnumField(Platform, max_length=10, null=True)
```

The campaign holds both Twitter and FB campaigns.

The objective field was a free text, but I am not happy with it.

I would like to create 2 different enums (enum34):

```
class FacebookObjective(Enum):
  MOBILE_APP_ENGAGEMENT
  MOBILE_APP_DOWNLOAD

class TwitterObjective(Enum):
  VIDEO_VIEWS_PREROLL
  TWEET_ENGAGEMENTS
```

and somehow use them on the same column. but not sure how to do it.

I thought to use enum, because I need the other uses to use it easily in the code. e.g:

```
TwitterObjective.VIDEO_VIEWS_PREROLL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (which isn't much where Django is concerned), to make this work you'll need to use a single `Enum` per field.  So in your case I would put the Twitter or FB designation in the name of the members:

```
Class Objective(Enum):
    FB_MOBILE_APP_ENGAGEMENT
    FB_MOBILE_APP_DOWNLOAD
    TW_VIDEO_VIEWS_PREROLL
    TW_TWEET_ENGAGEMENTS
```

If you really want to use different `Enum`s you have a couple choices:

- use nested `Enum` classes (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35886825/208880)
- use two classes and have your implementation choose between them (which will require either embedding a FaceBook or Twitter code in the name, such as FB_ and TW_, or using unique names across the two `Enum`s so you can reverse the lookup when going from db to Python)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28842582/208880) may help with the details.

Comment: yep, but I was trying to solve it in a different way

Comment: thanks. If I use nested enum - will it work fine with django models?

Comment: @Dejell:  I have no idea.  I wasn't kidding when I said I don't know much about Django.